# Salvando dados do checkbox e enviando a outra activity

Tags: android, checkbox

Tenho uma lista de produtos, que vem de um banco de dados online, cada produto contem um checkbox, nome e valor. Qual seria a melhor forma para passar apenas os dados dos produtos marcados para uma nova activity? É um sistema similar a um carrinho de compras. Não queria fazer com SQLite, queria algo que fosse mais simples. Alguém pode ajudar?

Os dados são salvos na aqui:

```
private final List<String> idSelecionados = new ArrayList<>();
```

O código abaixo, representa o checkbox.

*OBS: Os dados seriam enviados para uma activity chamada "Detalhes" que possui apenas um listview...*

```
CheckBox checMarcado  = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);        

    checMarcado.setChecked(s.isMarcado());
    //Define uma tag para o checBox, para recuperar os dados quando for clicado no checkBox
    checMarcado.setTag(s);

    checMarcado.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        CheckBox check = (CheckBox) v;

        Serializando p = (Serializando) v.getTag();
        p.setMarcado(((CheckBox) v).isChecked());

        if (check.isChecked()) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Adicionado " + p.getQuantidade()+ " - " + p.getNome(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Faz uma checagem se existe o mesmo valor na lista de inteiros
            if(!idSelecionados.contains(p.getNome())){
                //Adiciona em uma lista para poder manipular os dados depois
                idSelecionados.add(p.getNome() + p.getQuantidade());


            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Desmarcado " + p.getNome(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Faz uma checagem se existe o mesmo valor na lista de inteiros
            if(!idSelecionados.contains(p.getNome())){
                //Remove da lista se existir na lista
                idSelecionados.remove(p.getNome() + p.getQuantidade());
            }

        }

    }
});
```

Comment: já tentou algo com Intent?

Comment: Poste seu código, co base nele poderemos te dar uma resposta!

Comment: Editei com o código do checkbox...
Ja tentei com intent sim, mas não consegui chamar na lista da activity de Detalhes...

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido... Passei da seguinte forma via Intent:
(Não sei se foi a correta, mas por hora, foi uma que funcionou bem para mim)

Enviando:

```
                    Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), Detalhes.class);
                    i.putExtra("lista", dados);
                    context.startActivity(i);
```

E para receber fiz assim:

```
    ArrayList<String> dados = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("lista");
```

No entanto, se alguem conhecer uma forma mais adequada, gostaria de ver... Vlw...